Avraham with a "ה" and Sarah (not Sari) were Tumtumim Gemora Yevamos 64a at the end of the page. If this is so how did Avram, get Hagar pregnant?
Avraham's organ was created new. Yevamos 64b. Tumtumim cannot reproduce. Everyone one holds that they can not reproduce. There is only one opinion that after surgery it could possibly be possible. This explains all the brother and sister drama.

The question refers to Yevamot 64b-65a, which reads:

אָמַר רַבִּי אַמֵּי: אַבְרָהָם וְשָׂרָה טוּמְטְמִין הָיוּ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״הַבִּיטוּ אֶל צוּר חֻצַּבְתֶּם וְאֶל מַקֶּבֶת בּוֹר נֻקַּרְתֶּם״, וּכְתִיב, ״הַבִּיטוּ אֶל אַבְרָהָם אֲבִיכֶם וְאֶל שָׂרָה תְּחוֹלֶלְכֶם״.

This is translated in Rabbi Adin Steinsaltz's interpolated commentary as:

Rabbi Ami said: Abraham and Sarah were originally tumtumin, people whose sexual organs are concealed and not functional, as it is stated: “Look to the rock from where you were hewn, and to the hole of the pit from where you were dug” (Isaiah 51:1), and it is written in the next verse: “Look to Abraham your father and to Sarah who bore you” (Isaiah 51:2), which indicates that sexual organs were fashioned for them, signified by the words hewn and dug, over the course of time.

The question, more clearly stated, is that we assume that only just now, before the conception of Yitzchak, are Avraham and Sarah both transformed. This would be at odds with his previously fathering Yishmael, which is clearly stated, rather than a derasha, in the Biblical text.
I haven't seen anyone address it, but a readily available answer would be that Rabbi Ami would say that Avraham's difficulty was addressed earlier, before Yishmael's conception, in Bereishit 15. And it is unclear when Sarah's difficulty was addressed, but it could have been later.

If you look at the commentary of Ben Yehoyada, it seems to be emphasizing the numerous prayers from Sarah about this and the details of her petition.
Essentially, her emphasis was in regard to the fact no limb is created without purpose, she was created with an infertile womb and she was created with breasts to nurse a baby. She accepted her condition reproductively, both barren and a Tumtum. But she argued to G-d, why then did you also give me breasts to nurse?

רבונו של עולם כל מה שבראת באדם לא בראת אבר לבטלה עינים לראות אזנים לשמוע וכו' דדים הללו שנתת בי למה? לא להניק? תן לי בן שאניק בהם!

Avraham was initially made physically whole and healed of his sterility, a doubled and redoubled revelation of kindness, to offset the Gevurah character of his future son, Yitzchok, because of Sarah's prayers. His reproductive organ was uncovered and then he made fertile and was able to conceive his first son, Yishmael via Hagar, the Egyptian.
But this still didn't answer the claim from Sarah about why she had been created with breasts to nurse. They would only become purposeful if Sarah became pregnant herself and gave birth to a son. That her breasts would only begin to fill with milk at the time of delivery of her child.
